# Database migration to AWS Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms, amazon-glacier

I am working on POC to migrate the old RDS MySQL database data to AWS glacier using DMS service.

This is the first time I am working on DMS so not sure whether data is moved over to s3 or just copied to s3 after executing the DMS task, I can still see the data in database. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: AWS DMS usually just "copy" data to the desired destination. AWS DMS connects to the source data store, reads the source data, and formats the data for consumption by the target data store. It then loads the data into the target data store. So, in order to decomission the old RDS MySQL database you'll have to clean it by yourself.

Comment: Here's the High-level explanation of DMS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.HighLevelView.html